# cloning micro sd card failed, dd commands correct?

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card

I have a cubieboard (similar to Raspberry Pi). I wanted to clone the 2GB micro sd card to a 8Gb card.

Commands issued:

```
umount (all partitions on sd)
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/root/image.img
change sd card
dd if=/root/image.img of=/dev/sdb
```

then in gparted I resized the data partition.

But the system did not boot. I have no log files nor monitor output.

Question: Are the dd commands correct? is it /dev/sdb and not /dev/sdb1?
This would be the one partition only.

Answer (score 0):

dd commands are correct, if the system doesn't boot I would guess that you need to restore grub (if it's linux), that is if you are sure that the `/dev/sdb` contains whole system. Try using [BootRepair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)